# How to resolve Mongoose Error - Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I am learning NodeJS and below is the query where I am stuck:

user.route.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
    console.log("route initialized");
    var ctrl = require("../controllers/user.controller");
    app.post("/api/createuser", ctrl.createUser);   
};
```

And createUser function in controller user.controller.js

```
var User = require("../models/user");
controller.createUser = function(req,res){
    var user = req.body;
    console.log(user);
    var userModel = new User(user);

    userModel.save(function(err, data){
        if(err){
            res.send("error occurred please try again");
        }else{
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
};
```

Now when I try to hit the URL http://localhost:3000/api/createuser through Postman, I am getting following mongo error

```
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

Now i dont have idea how to change my code to accomodate promises. Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) but you could pick others like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or the one from es6.

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

The mpromise promises library. Mongoose 5.0 will use native promises by default if available, otherwise no promises. You will still be able to set a custom promises library using `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`, however, mpromise will not be supported. (from https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/5.0-Deprecation-Warnings)

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose's function requires promise and they've deprecated callbacks now. 
So, both of these will throw this warning on server,

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db');

mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db', function(err, res) {

});
```

For fixing this issue, you can use 3rd party libraries like blurbird or you can use ES6 native promises. I usually prefer later one, here's the snippet for es6 native promises

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db');
```

I hope it helps.